# Which database management system for a local (offline) small software?

Tags: c#, sql, database, entity-framework

I have spent a few days for implementation and testing some SQL-based database management system for my project. It's a small local shop management system, supposed to be sold to many of users  and shop owners. It will be an offline system for owners and the staff  of the shop, so we need to **secure the database** from unwanted accesses. I need a SQL database management system that works with **.NET Winform (C#)** **EntityFramework** and **easy to build an installer package**. These are what we have tried:

- SQL server Express 2012: SQL database, free, works well with .NET and Entity Framework but pretty hard to build a perfect installer for users without having them to manually install SQL Server System on their computer and it **doesn't protect the database from unwanted accesses**.
- Localdb: portable, free, works well with .NET and EF, easy to deploy, very reliable but again, **not secure**.
- SQL Compact Edition: almost the same as Localdb, has its own password encryption feature for the database but has been deprecated, isn't stable enough and doesn't work really well with EF.
  SQLite: just like SQL Compact edition.
- SQL server 2016 Developer edition: same as SQL Server Express, plus the database encrytion (TDE), but I haven't figured out how to make a good installer.

There are tons of software like this out there, how did they solve these problems?

Comment: Developer Edition isn't licensed for production

Comment: LocalDB is designed for that purpose. Why are you saying it is not secure? What are your specific security requirements?

Comment: Will the database be on a common computer/server at the client ? I understand it's offline, but is it also single computer ?

Comment: https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/providers/index.html Have you think about PostgreSQL or MySQL?

Comment: Regarding easy-install and update. You can run database system with docker, Both Postgres and MySQL have official docker images. run a local docker and start a database container, and all you need to do is config and use the connection string in your app. You may need to ship the docker and the official database image if the client doesn't have internet access.

Comment: @Orilux LocalDB is very good for my development, but  anyone has access to the customer's computer can read and edit the database (.mdf file) without any restriction. It's not appropriate for my software.

Comment: @Searching Yes, the software will be installed on a shared computer at the client. I prefer it to be single computer (the application and the database will be on the same computer), but it is not limited to.

Comment: @salitio sounds like good options. I haven't tried them yet, but do they work well with EntityFramework too?

Comment: @FlySoFast, Both are officially supported by EF core now, and they can be used with EF6 as well.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like SQLite will suit your bill. Entity Framework does have an SQLite provider and the database itself requires no server software or other infrastructure to be set up, it’s literally just a file.

If you really want to make it secure, you could encrypt the entire database, but that would have certain memory and CPU requirements to work with. If you encrypt individual fields, the schema and individual fields will be visible. Foreign keys could be difficult with such setup.

Comment: SQLite has lots of migration limitations, not suitable for production as well.
https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/providers/sqlite/limitations.html